# QuickBlox android session userinfo is null

Tags: android, session, webrtc, quickblox

I am using the quickblox for Android 23 API . I want to include user info from one caller to another, just before the call is established. 
For that I have used the 'userinfo' part of QBRTCSession and put in a key value pair. But for the other end, its giving  null value for 'userinfo'. Could anyone please suggest the possible reason and suggest a solution?

The session id is same in both the calls.  Start  call function-

```
  private void startCall(boolean isVideoCall) {
    if (opponentsAdapter.getSelectedItems().size() > Consts.MAX_OPPONENTS_COUNT) {
        Toaster.longToast(String.format(getString(R.string.error_max_opponents_count),
                Consts.MAX_OPPONENTS_COUNT));
        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG
            , "startCall()");
    //ArrayList<Integer> opponentsList = CollectionsUtils.getIdsSelectedOpponents(opponentsAdapter.getSelectedItems());
    ArrayList<Integer> opponentsList = new ArrayList<>();
    opponentsList.add(currentOpponentsList.get(0).getId());
    QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType conferenceType = isVideoCall
            ? QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_VIDEO
            : QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_AUDIO;
    QBRTCClient qbrtcClient = QBRTCClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    QBRTCSession newQbRtcSession = qbrtcClient.createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponentsList, conferenceType);
    newQbRtcSession.getUserInfo().put("som","name");
    Log.v("SessionThing",newQbRtcSession.getSessionDescription().toString());

    WebRtcSessionManager.getInstance(this).setCurrentSession(newQbRtcSession);
 //   newQbRtcSession.

    PushNotificationSender.sendPushMessage(opponentsList, "Hello"+currentUser.getFullName());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    CallActivity.start(this, false);

    Log.d(TAG, "conferenceType = " + conferenceType);
}
```

In call activity-

```
  public void onReceiveNewSession(final QBRTCSession session) {
    Log.d("userinfo_needed", "Session " + session.getSessionID() + " are income");
    Log.v("qbrtcsession",session.getSessionDescription().toString());
    userInfo = session.getUserInfo();
    if (getCurrentSession() != null) {
        //userInfo = session.getUserInfo();
        Log.d(TAG, "Stop new session. Device now is busy");
        session.rejectCall(null);
    }
}
```

In IncomeCallFragment - The toast gives null

```
  private void initUI(View view) {
    callTypeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.call_type);

    ImageView callerAvatarImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_caller_avatar);
    callerAvatarImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getBackgroundForCallerAvatar(currentSession.getCallerID()));

    TextView callerNameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_caller_name);

    QBUser callerUser = qbUserDbManager.getUserById(currentSession.getCallerID());
    callerNameTextView.setText(UsersUtils.getUserNameOrId(callerUser, currentSession.getCallerID()));
    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),currentSession.getSessionDescription().getUserInfo()+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    TextView otherIncUsersTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_other_inc_users);
    otherIncUsersTextView.setText(getOtherIncUsersNames());

    alsoOnCallText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_also_on_call);
    setVisibilityAlsoOnCallTextView();

    rejectButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.image_button_reject_call);
    takeButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.image_button_accept_call);
    accept();
}
```

Comment: Where you are calling session.startcall() .??

Comment: did u got answer ?

Comment: @user2828360 did u got any solution? please reply

Answer (score 1):

Once you create the Session set The Map in session for start call :

```
public static Map<String,String> createSessionUserInfo(){
    // Make sure you do not add anything null in this Map. Otherwise it will throw Exception,
    // So add blank string instead of null
    Map<String,String> userInfo=new HashMap<>();
    userInfo.put("img_user" , "img_url_here");
    userInfo.put("name_user" , "name_here");
    return userInfo;
}
```

Then add this info to start call :

```
 Map<String,String> userInfo= createSessionUserInfo();
            currentCallSession.startCall(userInfo);
```

On the Opponent end you will receive this session in onReceiveNewSession() and its the default behavior.:

```
 @Override
public void onReceiveNewSession(final QBRTCSession qbrtcSession) {
    try {
        Map<String, String> userSessionInfo = qbrtcSession.getUserInfo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you are still facing problem .

Comment: we tried it but its still not working, it seems like its not even calling onReceiveNewSession() method. This is in our start call- 
QBRTCSession newQbRtcSession = qbrtcClient.createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponentsList, conferenceType);
         Map<String,String> userinfo = new HashMap<>();
        userinfo.put("a",name);
        newQbRtcSession.startCall(userinfo);
        
WebRtcSessionManager.getInstance(this).setCurrentSession(newQbRtcSession);
We are using the sample app of videocalling by Quickblox.

Comment: You sure that name you are passing in map is not null or blank ??Edit your question with code ..

Comment: i don't see your session.startcall(userInfo) call . Where are you calling it ?

Comment: @ADM . for me in receving side  got userinfo null .                                                  Sender side code is below .
 WebRtcSessionManager.getInstance(this).setCurrentSession(newQbRtcSession);
       WebRtcSessionManager.getInstance(this).getCurrentSession().startCall(userInfo);

Comment: Are you sure the userInfo is null or empty in this case debug the code.

Comment: @ADM yes , i m sure . is it sending code format is wrong ?please check

Comment: Code looks well . post your gradle of quick blox dependencies .