# how to get full name of QBuser - QuickBlox

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using `QuickBlox` for making a video chat application, what I have to do is to call the person having same `roomname` and `username` but don't know how to get the full names of users from the list.

how i can get full names of users from `opponentAdapter`

```
 private void startCall(boolean isVideoCall) {
        if (opponentsAdapter.getSelectedItems().size() > Consts.MAX_OPPONENTS_COUNT) {
            Toaster.longToast(String.format(getString(R.string.error_max_opponents_count),Consts.MAX_OPPONENTS_COUNT));
            return;
        }


        Log.d(TAG, "startCall()");
        ArrayList<Integer> opponentsList = CollectionsUtils.getIdsSelectedOpponents(opponentsAdapter.getSelectedItems());
        QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType conferenceType = isVideoCall
                ? QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_VIDEO
                : QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType.QB_CONFERENCE_TYPE_AUDIO;

        QBRTCClient qbrtcClient = QBRTCClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+opponentsList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        QBRTCSession newQbRtcSession = qbrtcClient.createNewSessionWithOpponents(opponentsList, conferenceType);

        WebRtcSessionManager.getInstance(this).setCurrentSession(newQbRtcSession);

        PushNotificationSender.sendPushMessage(opponentsList, currentUser.getFullName());

        CallActivity.start(this, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "conferenceType = " + conferenceType);
    }
```

Comment: Which list ? Add your code in question .

Comment: just added the code

Answer (score 2):

Well there can be 2 scenario .
**1.** Get User details on Caller end :- This can be done easily cause at the time of calling you already have `opponentsList` of `QbUser` so you can just use it from the list .

**2.** Get caller and other Opponent info on opponent end :- At this time you will not have the caller and Opponent info with `QBRTCSession` . It only holds the list of ids of membres i.e `ArrayList<Integer> opponentsList`.

To provide extra information in `QBRTCSession` you can use `UserInfo` attribute for `Session`.
I have provided an answer for creating User Info [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47137359/4168607) . You can have a look at it . Just make Make sure you do not add anything null in this Map. Otherwise it will throw `Exception` because of internal XMl parsing(This was an issue in an old release maybe it is resolved now).